# Need to set Related To on a Pardot created Task

Tags: tasks, pardot

Pardot creates some Tasks for agents to contact a potential customer but the marketing team is saying they cannot set the Related To field to be the Account for the Contact.  So I tried setting the Account via a trigger but not getting it to work.

I tried:

```
trigger TestTaskTrigger on Task (before insert) {
  for (Task t : trigger.new){ 
    String c = t.Who.Name;
    Id a = [select AccountId from contact where name = :c];
    t.What = a;
 } 
}
```

This just generates an error of Illegal assignment from List to Id

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `t.WhatId`?  You also need to move that query outside the loop

Comment: Also this sounds like a Pardot issue with the connector and you shouldn't have to do all of this work

Comment: I have not looked at Pardot I was advised by the people doing that side that Pardot can not set the Account on the Task. That could be possible and I could have them investigate that further if you think it should be able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised Answer:

Heres what I would do if I were you

Trigger

```
trigger TestTaskTrigger on Task (before insert) {
       if(trigger.isInsert && trigger.isBefore){
            Task_Methods.setWhat(trigger.new);
        }
}
```

Class

```
public class Task_Methods{
    public static void setWhat(List<Task> newList){
        List<Task> tList = new List<Task>();
        Map<Id,Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id,Contact>([SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId != null]);

        for(Task t : newList){
            if(contactMap.get(t.WhoId) != null){
                 t.WhatId = contactMap.get(t.WhoId).AccountId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this and get List has no rows for assignment to SObject when trying to create a new task with a contact on it of course

Comment: You're not going to get any results for the t.who.name within your trigger. I would recommend sending trigger.new to a helper class and then querying the who.name value and setting the WhatId that way. You're also going to need to determine if the who is a Lead or a Contact. I believe there is a WhoType field you can use for that.

Comment: I will look at creating a solution using these suggestions. TY

Comment: Wow this revised answer looks excellent. I will try that out

Comment: Error: No such column 'AccountId' on entity 'Name'

Comment: It is working. Excellent

Comment: Ah, yeah that's right. Revised the code again. If you don't have a ton of Contacts, you could take that approach. If you do have a ton of Contacts, then you could always loop over trigger.new to add the Who Id's to a set, then pass the set to the method and build the contactMap using 'WHERE Id in contactSet' to limit the number of rows returned.